# Edge Connected Proof

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that if $G$ is a $k$-edge-connected graph and $e$ is an edge of $G$, then $G-e$ is $(k-1)$-edge-connected.

Assume that $G-e$ is not $(k-1)$-edge-connected. Then there exists a set $X$ containing $k-2$ edges such that $(G-e)-X$ is disconnected.

Where do I go from here? Any hints or different approaches are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Then $X \cup \{e\}$ is a set of $k-1$ edges such that when removed from $G$...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $G$ is $k$-edge-connected but $G-e$ is not $(k-1)$-edge-connected. We arrive at a contradiction. Since $G-e$ is not $(k-1)$-edge-connected, there exists a set $X$ of $k-2$ edges such that $G-e-X$ is disconnected.  Thus there exists a set of $k-1$ edges $X \dot{\cup} \{e\}$ whose removal from $G$ disconnects $G$.  Thus, $G$ is not $k$-edge-connected, a contradiction.